# May I upgrade laptop memory with a dual-rank module RAM?

Tags: laptop, memory, lenovo-laptop

My Laptop ( Lenovo Edge E531 ) has two RAM slots. By default It has one *SK Hynix 4GB DDR3-1600 SODIMM PC3L-12800S* **Single Rank** *x8 Module* and the other slot is empty. May I launch one *SK Hynix 8GB DDR3-1600 SODIMM PC3L-12800S* **Dual Rank** *x8 Module* and upgrade the memory capacity to 12GB? Will it work smoothly without any extra configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this will work correctly after the BIOS sorts things out,
although the performance you will achieve is unpredictable,
but will be at least as good as your single-rank RAM.

I base my answer on the
[Edge E531 (ThinkPad) Memory Reference guide](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-edge-laptops/thinkpad-edge-e531/parts/pd014502-memory-reference-guide)
which lists RAM sticks for 2Rx4 and 2RX8.

Note that in the notation 2Rx4 & 2Rx8, 2R represents Dual Rank.
A  Rank is a data block which is 64 bits wide without
Error Correction Code (ECC), and is 72 bits wide with ECC.
The x4 & x8 refers to the number
of banks on the memory component or chip. The higher the number of
banks, the fewer the chips in the memory module, the better the
reliability and power consumption.

Most motherboards support mixing
memory modules of different ranks and number of banks.

Comment: Thank you! Should I change any setting of motherboard after installing the new RAM on its slot?

Comment: The motherboard should do it automatically.

Comment: On the memories specifications I noticed one of them (4GB) has 512M value for **Depth** item while the other RAM (8GB) has 1G value for it. Could the difference on this item affect the performance?

Comment: See [Memory geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_geometry), but it shouldn't be a problem. In any case, as RAM compatibility is very complex, always buy RAM from a vendor with a good return policy.